# Does the method behind finding the basis of a vector space change when looking at some subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let me give an example.

Let $P_2$ be the vector space of all polynomials of degree 2 or less. Take $H$ to be the subspace spanned by:

$x−14x^2−6, −(12x^2+5)$ and  $34x^2+x+14$

I know the dimension of $P_2$ is 3, and a basis is $(x^2, x, 1)$. I worked this out quite easily by just finding the set of polynomials that span $P_2$ and then showing they are linearly independent by reducing the appropriate matrix to RREF where it's rank was 3.

I wasn't sure if the same could be done to find the basis of the subspace $H$ or if the method changes slightly. This is my working out for now:

$\left[\begin{array}{l}-14&1&-6\\-12&0&-5\\34&1&14\end{array}\right]$ $. . . $$\left[\begin{array}{l}1&0&\frac{5}{12}\\0&1&-\frac{1}{6}\\0&0&0\end{array}\right]$

By the Rank Theorem, we have 2 pivot columns so the rank is 2. So the dimension is 2. This is where I got up to. My question is, to find the basis of this subspace do I just pick 2 of the 3 polynomials? My reasoning for this is because any 2 would still span the subspace and it has to be 2 to begin with since the dimension is 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I do my row reduction, I see that I have made a basic arithmetic error.

As this matrix is rank 2, any two linearly independent rows will form a suitable basis.  That would include the two rows you have after completing your row reduction work.

Comment: $$p_1=-14x^2+x-6$$ $$p_2=-12x^2-5$$ $$p_3=34x^2+x+14$$ $$-p_1+4p_2+p_3=0$$

Comment: I'm confused, how is the matrix's determinant not equal to 0? I checked my answer with a calculator and it says it's 0. Edit: What does the determinant exactly have to do with this method?

Comment: @mr_e_man So since the variables aren't forced to be 0, the set isn't linearly independent right? From the RREF matrix I calculated, the dimension of the subspace is 2 and the elements in it's basis are the 2 rows I have. Am I correct?

Comment: @BillCogn - Correct. (The matrix is singular.)

Comment: @mr_e_man Ah thank you, the other person was making me doubt myself